# How to draw an indeterminate ProgressBar for material card on android

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, progress-bar, android-progressbar

I have a list of material cards in my layout as follows and I am trying to load data from backend, while loading I would like to show a progress bar.
I have implemented a circular progressbar but would like to implement the loading for items as shown in the image below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="6dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    app:cardElevation="4dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/headingText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/appImage"
        android:paddingLeft="16sp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subHeaderText"
        style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/headingText"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/appImage"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:text="SubTiltle"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
    
</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

I have used simple progress bar horizontal and circular but not sure how to draw a progress bar for card loading I have found this https://github.com/zhanghai/MaterialProgressBar but not sure how to use it for my case.

[image]

Can anyone point out how to implement such loading?

In general is it possible for any layout to have such loading.

Comment: seeing as though you're not actually directly asking for libraries, I feel like my suggestion for [this](https://facebook.github.io/shimmer-android/) library could be fine. maybe it's what you're looking for

Comment: Use a progressBar or ProgressIndicator.